# Must an automorphism which fixes two fields necessarily fix their composite?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Suppose $K$ and $F$ are subfields of some field $L$, and $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $L$ which fixes $K$ and $F$. Must $\sigma$ fix the composite $KF$?

Reading through chapter 14 of Dummit it seems the answer is yes, but I cannot see why. $\sigma$ clearly fixes $K\cap F$, but could not there be some element of $KF$ which is in neither $K$ nor $F$, which is not fixed by $\sigma$? When $KF/K\cap F$ is Galois, the answer is yes by the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, but I cannot reason out why it must be true in general.

I have tried looking at things like $K=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt 2)$, $F=\mathbf{Q}(\pi)$, $L = \mathbf{C}$, but I realized I am not sure what automorphisms which fix $F$ look like, or what $KF$ looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$KF$ is the smallest subfield of $L$ containing $K$ and $F$. The field $L^{\sigma}$ contains $K$ and $F$ by hypothesis, so, by definition, it contains the smallest subfield of $L$ containing $K$ and $F$, that is, $KF$.

If $K$ and $F$ are finite extensions of some base field $E$, you can get an explicit description of the composite as follows (for the general case, refer to J. Darné's answer):
$$KF=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nk_if_i\ \colon n\in\mathbb{N},k_i\in K,f_i\in F\right\}.$$
The explicit description can come in handy at times, but I think it's often more useful to think of $KF$ in terms of its defining property, i.e. being the smallest subfield containing $K$ and $F$.

An automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is the complex conjugation. Others (a lot even) exist, but are non-explicit and quite misbehaved.

Comment: Ah thank you. I forgot that the elements of $L$ fixed by $\sigma$ form a subfield of $L$.

Comment: This description does not hold in general. Of course, it works for finite extensions, but consider $K = \mathbb C (X)$ and $F =  \mathbb C (Y)$ inside  $KF = \mathbb C (X,Y)$. Then $\frac1{X-Y}$ is an element of the composite extension, but does not belong the the linear span of products of elements of $K$ by elements of $F$, does it ?

Comment: @J.Darné You are absolutely right. I'll edit this in immediately. I've a bad habit of neglecting to mention finiteness, so thanks a lot for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes : elements of $KF$ are all that you can obtained from elements of K and F by applying the field operations to elements of K and of F (they are algebraic fractions in elements of K and F). 
As a consequence, $\sigma$, which fixes all elements of K and F and preserves the field operations, must preserve all these elements.

If you want to write it down completely, you can take :
$$A := \left\{\frac{P(k_1, ..., k_n,f_1, ..., f_m)}{Q(k_1, ..., k_n,f_1, ..., f_m)} \middle| P, Q \in \mathbb C[X_1, ..., X_n,Y_1, ..., Y_m],\ k_1,..., k_n \in K,\ f_1, ..., f_n \in F,\ Q(k_1, ..., k_n,l_1, ..., l_m) \neq 0 \right\},$$
then $A$ is a subfield of $L$, and it is obviously the smallest containing $K$ and $F$, thus $A = KF$. And it is easy to see that $\sigma$ must preserve these elements.

Comment: Did you mix up $L$ and $F$ a few times? Perhaps my confusion comes from a poor understanding of the composite of two fields. Dummit defines $KF$ as the smallest subfield of $L$ which contains both $K$ and $F$. I guess I do not immediately see the connection to ``all the elements obtained by applying the field operations to elements of $K$ and of $F$''.

Comment: Well, most of the time these definitions are indeed equivalent. Intuitively, the smallest algebraic structure generated from given conditions must at least contain the algebraic operations and on the other hand the thing generated by considering all algebraic operations is an algebraic structure. This holds for groups, normal groups, vector spaces and so seems to be at least plausible for composite fields

Comment: It is more than plausible : it is true !